# EmberJS computed sort property conflicting with jQuery UI Sortable

Tags: ember.js, jquery-ui-sortable

I am having an issue with getting drag-and-drop sort functionality with EmberJS working.

The tutorials that cover this issue don't provide any help on the initial sort, which I am doing through a computed property.

What I'm encountering seems to be a race condition between ember's rerender when the `sortedItems` computed property changes and jQueryUI Sortable updating the DOM. List Items get duplicated, or disappear altogether upon sorting.

### Route

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return Ember.Object.create({
      id: 1,
      title: "Title",
      subtitle: "Subtitle",
      items: [
        Ember.Object.create({
          name: "Item 2",
          sortOrder: 2,
          id: 1
        }),
        Ember.Object.create({
          name: "Item 1",
          sortOrder: 1,
          id: 2
        }),
        Ember.Object.create({
          name: "Item 3",
          sortOrder: 3,
          id: 3
        })
      ]
    });
  }
});
```

### Controller

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({

  sortProperties: [ 'sortOrder' ],
  sortedItems: Ember.computed.sort('model.items', 'sortProperties'),

  actions: {
    updateSortOrder: function(indexes) {
      this.get('items').forEach(function(item) {
        var index = indexes[item.get('id')];
        item.set('sortOrder', index);
      });
    }
  }

});
```

### View

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.View.extend({

  didInsertElement: function() {
    var controller = this.get('controller');

    this.$(".item-list").sortable({
      update: function(event, ui) {
        var indexes = {};

        $(this).find('li').each(function(index) {
          indexes[$(this).data('id')] = index;
        });

        controller.send('updateSortOrder', indexes);
      }
    })
  }
});
```

### Template

```
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
<h2>{{ subtitle }}</h2>

<ul class="item-list">
  {{#each item in sortedItems }}
    <li data-id="{{ unbound item.id }}">
      name: {{ item.name }}<br />
      sortOrder: {{ item.sortOrder }}<br />
      id: {{ item.id }}
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Here's a Barebones Ember app that reproduces the issue: https://github.com/silasjmatson/test-sortable

### Question

Is there a way to avoid this race condition or sort only once when the controller is initialized?

*Apologies if there is already an answer on the interwebs for this. I haven't been able to resolve this despite a week of searching/experimenting.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sort only once when the controller is initialised:

```
sortedItems: Ember.computed(function() {
    return Ember.get(this, 'model.items').sortBy('sortOrder');
})
```

Because you're using the computed sort property it is attempting to sort the list for you whenever the sortOrder property changes on any item, which is rerendering the #each and doing something funky.

Just sort once initially using the method above and then let jQuery handle the order of items - rather than jQuery and Ember.

Comment: That will actually sort the list when you first access the 'sortedItems' property.. So it's actually after the controller in initialized.

Comment: I'd give you 500 stackoverflow points if I could, @jmurphyau.